# How to implement "slow scrollview like camera mode option" in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

```
// here is my recyclerview layoutmanager setup

     layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false){
                @Override
                public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position) {
                    LinearSmoothScroller smoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(recyclerView.getContext()) {
                        private static final float SPEED = 300f;// Change this value (default=25f)
                        @Override
                        protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
                            return SPEED / displayMetrics.densityDpi;
                        }

                    };
                    smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
                    startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
                }
            };
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
//
```

I am implementing camera in my android application.I have fruits name instead of(video,photo,square,panorama,manual) normal modes.I want to implement the slow scroll like normal camera app when user selecting options in camera.

Comment: Where you need scroll? options?

Comment: as i checked in my OnePlus 6t camera, there is no `recyclerview`. In reality they use tabs with `viewpager`. when you swipe, you actually changing the tab, that's why it look like slow scroll

Comment: can anyone please give me code